# Insert thousands of docs in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

What is the best way to insert thousands of rows into a collection in Meteor?

When I am inserting inside a loop, I can see on the page that the number of docs updates reactively due to `Collection.find().count()`. I am not interested in knowing the number of documents before the loop is over and all the docs are inserted. Are there any good practices to remember when inserting large amount of data in MongoDB?

## Edit

When I use

```
createFolders: function() {
  var folders = [];

  for   (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    folders.push({ name: i });
  }

  Folders.batchInsert(folders);
},
```

the docs are inserted but the server says `RangeError: Out of memory` and restarts.

Comment: How many are we talking about ? ~

Comment: Access the underlying node driver and use ["Bulk"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) operations. Not one of the abtract drivers is optimized in this way.

Comment: @Pogrindis "thousands" of course!

Comment: Around 10.000 docs inserted at once.

Comment: https://atmospherejs.com/mikowals/batch-insert i hear good things about this

Comment: You aren't going to get great answers here, unless you are prepared to wait. As I said. Look for accessors to the underlying driver and use the "Bulk" ( I thought it was cute someone thought copying that link makes an answer ) operations as linked to before. It's the smartest way to do it. Otherwise you have 10,000 insert requests and 10,000 responses to wait for. With "Bulk" it actually reduces over network traffic to 10 requests and a single returned response.

Answer (score 1):

Meteor does not have a default functionality to do bulk inserts so your autorun will trigger every insert operation

This is a package that enables batch loads - mikowals:batch-insert

Answer (score 0):

If you're not interested in getting everything published to the database all the time for every user, you can just remove the autopublish package from your project,`meteor remove autopublish`, if you haven't already. This way, you can restrict the meteor magic from happening until after you have inserted all of the rows. When you are done inserting, you can use `meteor.publish` on the entire collection to 'push' it to all of the users.

Not entirely sure if this was what you were thinking, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to pass an array of documents to a single collection.insert() call

Mongo also provides some bulk insert operation.  See here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/

Not sure if they are supported in Meteor though.